# Library to convert svg to jpg or png image

Tags: javascript, image, svg, png, jpeg

I want tot convert an svg element into jpeg or png image format. Please can anyone refer me some javascript code or library to convert svg element into jpg or png image?

Comment: Please may you read [help/on-topic]?

Comment: This answer might help  https://stackoverflow.com/a/3514404/18333498

Comment: @DeepDev the ans is not complete there

Comment: Do not expect answers to be complete. Instead they should get you going so you can finish it yourself